# All disease and sickness suddenly cured in humanity, what happens next?

Tags: society, economy

It’s 2018 and a powerful magic is used to warp reality. Every living human suffering from any disease or sickness is suddenly cured as if it never existed (down to a genetic level). However, this is but a one time deal. Sickness and disease may still be found in and contracted through the world around humanity.

Having received this great boon, what happens next? How would humanity realistically go forward after this?

Edit - I suppose the potential answers are rather open ended (which I know is a no-no). For one particular aspect more than anything else, I would like to know how this effects the economy as a whole and health oriented organizations in particular as well as what changes that (the economic) would bring about in society. Answers that fit what I’m looking for should address the short term, long term, and why.

---

Clarifications...

- Anything perceived as being a disease or sickness qualifies.
- The idea for the genetic fix is that the next generation isn’t suddenly going inherit what the previous generation simply stopped showing signs of. Things could still presumably happen down the road, but let’s just say that the genetic material is simply replaced with its closest non-sickness producing relative.

Comment: This question is extremely opinion based.  Please edit to include constraints on answers and a method for determining what makes one answer better than another.

Comment: People with terminal illnesses would celebrate, the world population would have a brief surge, the economy would either go up due to more spenders or down due to more retirees, certain doctors wouldn't have 20 hour shifts for a couple months... there are many things that could happen, is there anything in particular you're looking for? "How would all of humanity work if an unprecedented change happened" is a bit broad.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "down to the genetic level"? A lot of genetic conditions aren't really diseases, and exist because there's some other (actual) disease they protect against. Also, where is the replacement genetic material going to come from? If its a recessive condition, are you just replacing one of the two genes (removing the condition, but leaving the person a carrier)?

Comment: Currently this question looks like a [High Concept](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/28789) without any real problem that you encountered while working out the consequences of this change you just introduced. What specifically are you looking for? And what do you expect from answers? Currently it looks to me like "A few days of celebration before the first one gets the cold again" would be exactly equally valid as "Incredible Ups in the stock market due to happiness", which is equally valid as "Confusion breaks out and the stock market crashes".

Comment: For the moment I am voting to temporarily put this question on hold as "primarily opinion-based" until it's been [edit]ed to provide more information about how answers will be judged and what kind of problems were encountered while creating the world that followed from this premise.

Comment: Why does this question have the *dystopia* tag, it seems more *utopian*...

Comment: @colmde - The way in which I perceive events taking place leads to a more dystopian future. That said, I would be interested in how you see it ultimately creating a utopia instead.

Comment: @JustSnilloc - just simply because disease has been eliminated...one of the ingredients for a perfect society

Comment: I've VTC'd for primarily story based rather than opinion based - the point is that what happens next is your story. Any number of scenarios could plausibly play out. Choose the most interesting one! If you're unsure about a scenario, you can ask about it here. The reverse of this question (ie Is this scenario plausible given the circumstances) seems perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: I add a suggestion: **catastrophe**. The Healing  is tangible proof of the existence of Someone who can do things on the scale of the Healing (duh). The impact of this proof is apocalyptic - uncertainty runs rampant (what will *They* do next?), stock exchanges collapse, extremists everywhere go on the rampage, certain that He - whoever He is - has joined their battle. We will probably avoid WW III, but it will take many years before we heal from the Healing.

Comment: Many diseases that are not 100% human-only will sneak back, because nobody takes precautions any more. *Especially* VDs.

Comment: @bendl Perhaps you should go and acquaint yourself with the criteria for Too Story Based, then you would see that your VTC was erroneous. Please note the VTC says TOO Story Based which implies some degree of story is allowed in worldbuilding. You're welcome.

Comment: @a4android I'm not sure why the hostility... Having read the Too Story Based criteria plenty of times, I still think that my VTC is valid. The root of Too Story Based is: "You are asking questions about a story set in a world instead of about building a world." OP has a world where all disease is cured and wants to know what _could_ or _would_ happen next. That is exactly the definition of too story based. That being said, there is overlap between Too Story Based and Opinion Based and Too Broad, so an Opinion Based or Too Broad VTC is also valid.

Comment: @bendl I'm not being hostile, simply educational. Story based's criteria involves the actions of characters. Something this question doesn't ask about. There is nothing about a story set in a world. It asks about a world without illness. The other VTC reasons are better choices. Too Broad VTC would be valid. Opinion based could fail due to knowing what the consequences of diseases, so their removal can be worked out.

Answer (score 2):

Fact-based answer:

1. thousands of man-hours are suddenly available for work .. but can the human race take advantage of the surplus?
2. Pharmaceutical companies switch to producing health aids .. vitamin pills etc .. so their income does not drop off.
3. medical research shifts to degenerative and mechanical problems so the labs keep their research grants. Prosthetics takes off. Cosmetic surgery advances.

Issues that I have with the Question

1. does the Healing include mental disease?
2. Do you distinguish between psychological problems and neurological problems? As in .. neurological disease is cured but schizophrenics are still crazy?
3. does the world get warning of the Healing event in advance? If not the Healing Event is not noticed except as a drop in infectious diseases but as people reinfect and the occurrence of disease returns to normal.
4. Is the agency of the Healing the immune system of each individual? if so is everyone now "inoculated" against all bacterial infections and virus caused diseases? If so there will be a long-term reduction in infectious disease .. Big Pharma takes a huge hit .. hundreds of thousands out of work.
5. does the Healing remove bacteria from the world outside of human bodies? Your question seems to imply not as you allow for infections to reoccur after the Healing Event.
6. ditto 5 for Viruses.

I have to say that upon reflection, your question is a waste of time as it is not well-bounded enough to allow for a discussion of possibilities to proceed.

Comment: 1 - Yes | 2 - No, but chemical/hormonal balances are restored | 3 - No | 4 - No, only the direct cause is fixed/removed | 5 - It removes anything that is part of the body (on or under skin) and nothing else. | Even after the edit?

Comment: @JustSnilloc put this comment into your original question and it can get re-opened.